# How to read bin file located in java project's folder in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file, file-io, bin

I want to read bin file in java. I create folder that's name is doc in project's folder and I added bin files in doc folder. I want to read with this code;

```
String fileName = "10.bin";
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int readBytes;

try {
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    while((readBytes = in.read(data)) != -1){

    System.out.println("read " + readBytes + "bytes, and placed them into temp array named data");
    }
    in.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This bin file named as 10.bin is in doc folder as you can see in picture

[image]

I can not access file with this code. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to give the path of the fileName

```
File fileName = new File("your fileName path goes here");
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
```